# Run a method in AppDelegate for a Controller which is not the first

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, appdelegate

I'm configuring Handoff in my app. For an app structured in this way

> `(Entry Point)` -> `UINavigationController` ->
>   `InterestedViewController`

that's enough:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let win = self.window {
            let navController = win.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            let viewController = navController.topViewController as! myViewController

            viewController.restoreUserActivityState(userActivity)
    }
    return true
}
```

When app is launched using Handooff, this method run in AppDelegate and launch method `func restoreUserActivityState(activity: NSUserActivity)` in "myViewController" and everything works.

Trouble is that my app is structured in another way:

> `(Entry Point)` -> `Another ViewController with animated logo` -> `UINavigationController` -> `InterestedViewController`

so the previous code doesn't work. I can't understand how to adapt the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {   // Handoff

    if let win = window {
        let presentationController = win.rootViewController as! PresentationController
        let navController = presentationController.presentedViewController as! UINavigationController
        let viewController = navController.topViewController as! myViewController

        viewController.restoreUserActivityState(userActivity)
    }

    return true
}
```